# Copy a value down n-times

Tags: vba, excel

I have two tables: "VALUES" and "INSERT". In Table "INSERT" the cell "A1" contains a value that needs to be coped down as many times as there are rows > "" in "VALUES"

I have tried the following code but it does not work as I intended but copies the value of "A1"  4 times every other row in "VALUES".

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!

```
Sub InsertValuePart()
Dim maxRow As Integer
Dim calcVal As String
Dim x As String
Dim i As Long
Sheets("VALUES").Select
maxRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Sheets("INSERT").Select
Cells(1, 1).Activate
x = Cells(1, 1).Value

Cells(2, 1).Select

For i = 1 To maxRow
Cells(i, 1).Value = x
i = i + 1
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to define `i` as it is treated in your `for` command. Also a `for` command will automatically iterate over each value so using `i = i + 1` will give you values of `i = 1, 3, 5`. If you do not include that then `i = 1,2,3,....,maxRow`. Also `calcVal` was not used anywhere so I got rid of it.

```
Sub InsertValuePart()
Dim maxRow As Integer
Dim x As String

maxRow = Sheets("VALUES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
x = Sheets("INSERT").Cells(1, 1).Value

For i = 1 to maxRow
    Sheets("INSERT").Cells(i,1).Value = x
Next

Sheets("INSERT").Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Another way to do it is listed below on one line:

```
Sub InsertValuePart()
    Sheets("INSERT").Range("A1", "A" & CStr(Sheets("VALUES").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)).Value = Sheets("INSERT").Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I used "Option explicit" and thus, I had to declare i. The other variable was for a later action. But your script works just fine :) Thanks!